# Unable to make collaborative editing work using Prosemirror

Tags: javascript, node.js, editor, prose-mirror

I am using prosemirror to build a collaborative editor, where multiple people can edit one document. I wrote the following code, based on the example given here - http://prosemirror.net/docs/guides/collab/

Here is the code-

```
const { EditorState } = require('prosemirror-state'); 
const { EditorView } = require('prosemirror-view');
const { DOMParser } = require("prosemirror-model");
const {schema} = require("./schema");
var collab = require("prosemirror-collab");


function Authority(doc) {
  this.doc = doc
  this.steps = []
  this.stepClientIDs = []
  this.onNewSteps = []
}

Authority.prototype.receiveSteps = function(version, steps, clientID) {
  if (version != this.steps.length) return

  var self = this
  // Apply and accumulate new steps
  steps.forEach(function(step) {
    self.doc = step.apply(self.doc).doc
    self.steps.push(step)
    self.stepClientIDs.push(clientID)
  })
  // Signal listeners
  this.onNewSteps.forEach(function(f) { f() })
}

Authority.prototype.stepsSince = function(version) {
  return {
    steps: this.steps.slice(version),
    clientIDs: this.stepClientIDs.slice(version)
  }
}

var auth = new Authority('');
collabEditor(auth)

function collabEditor(authority) {
  var view = new EditorView(document.querySelector("#editor"), {
    state: EditorState.create({schema: schema, plugins: [collab.collab()]}),
    dispatchTransaction: function(transaction) {
      var newState = view.state.apply(transaction)
      view.updateState(newState)
      var sendable = collab.sendableSteps(newState)
      if (sendable)
        authority.receiveSteps(sendable.version, sendable.steps,
                               sendable.clientID)
    }
  })
   authority.onNewSteps.push(function() {
    var newData = authority.stepsSince(collab.getVersion(view.state))
    view.dispatch(
      collab.receiveTransaction(view.state, newData.steps, newData.clientIDs))
  })

  return view
}
```

When i run this code (after installing all the dependencies and setting up a simple server in nodejs) I am basically able to edit a text box but I am not able to open two tabs in chrome and see the collaboration happen. What am i doing wrong?

Will love some feedback.

Answer (score 3):

This is the example code for a simple, single-page, no-external-communication setup. As such, no, it won't communicate to other tabs. For that, you'd have to move the authority somewhere else and set up pages to actually communicate with it over HTTP or websockets. (See for example [this demo](https://github.com/ProseMirror/website/tree/master/src/collab).)